# Substring working in an unexpected fashion

Tags: vb.net, string

I am programming a Hangman game in Visual Basic for some college homework (as much as I hate Visual Basic- I prefer C++), and I have got myself slightly stuck.
When the player presses a letter on the on-screen keypad, the word needs to be checked for the presence of that letter, and to replace the specific character in the masked version of the string (a masked version of 'Apple' would be '*****', for example).

To replace the character I am illiterating through the `word` string, and performing a `substring` operation to replace the character position in the `maskedWord`.

[image]

The `Str = maskedWord.Substring(0, count) + CStr("A") + maskedWord.Substring(count + 1)` is fairly self-explanatory; we're cutting the character out and replacing it with the letter we want (in this case, 'A').
I've searched and searched for the solution to this, but I haven't found anything apart from the `Mid` function, which doesn't work properly.

I'm fairly sure that I programmed the 'Str = ' line correctly, but as can be seen in the screenshot, it doesn't work the way that had been intended. The word 'DUBITABLY' has the letter 'A' a character position '6', but instead the 'A' position in 'Str' is being put to position '1'.

Why is this happening, and how could I get 'Str' to format in the intended way?
I've verified that 'count' is being set correctly.

The code (I added the 'MsgBox' and a couple of other lines as diagnostic):

```
Private Sub btnA_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnA.Click
        btnA.Enabled = False 'Deactivates the button, so the player cannot use it again.
        If (InStr(word, "A")) Then 'If the letter is in the string
            Dim count As Integer = 0
            For Each c As Char In word 'We go over every char in the word..
                If (CStr(c) = "A") Then
                    Dim Str As String = maskedWord
                    'Str.Remove(count, 1).Insert(count, "A")
                    Str = maskedWord.Substring(0, count) + CStr("A") + maskedWord.Substring(count + 1)
                    MsgBox(Str)
                    count += 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: You really want to do this for each letter? Couldn't you do one `main function` and call it when a button is touched, so you`d have way less code

Comment: @returntrue Well as I said, this isn't the 'final code', it'll be improved once I get over this one small problem. To the downvoter: please state what's wrong with the question, instead of 'doing a runner'.

Comment: Why are you converting a string to a string?  `CStr("A")`?  The call to CStr is not needed here.  Also, in VB, you should use `&` for string concatenation.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Please read my last comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because you increment `count` only when you find a letter `A` in the `word`. You need to increment it at every iteration, whether you found anything or not.

Also, to warn you of your next problem - the `Str` variable gets initialized anew on each found instance of the letter, and you don't modify the `maskedWord` anywhere at all. But maybe you simply haven't gotten that far.

Other than that, yes, this is a pretty fine way of solving the task. Maybe not the most optimal - all those substrings and concatenations are creating tons of intermediate strings in the memory. But since the word is small anyway, this is totally OK.

If you had to do this for a long string (we're talking megabytes here), you could first convert it to characater array (via [`String.ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx)), then go through the array and modify the necessary elements, and lastly change it back to a string via [the appropriate constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9(v=vs.110).aspx).

Maybe that could simplify the code here too. Maybe not. Your call.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't gotten that far yet, and as @return true commented, it'll be one separate function to increase efficiency. I feel really stupid for making the (obvious) mistake- thanks for pointing it out to me!

Comment: @cybermonkey - No problem! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted. :) Good luck with the rest of the homework! Glad to see someone actually trying to solve it themselves, rather than just begging for a complete code on some Internet forum! :)